# Which one is the correct address of this char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char *str1 = "computer";

  printf ("%p\n", (void *)   str1);   // i
  printf ("%p\n", (void *)  &str1);   // ii
  printf ("%d\n",           *str1);   // iii
  printf ("%p\n", (void *)  *&str1);  // iv
  printf ("%p\n", (void *)  &*str1);  // v

  return 0;
}
```

I know that `&` is the '*address of*' operator and `*` is the '*value at address*' operator. 
According to me,

**i.** This is the address of the char array since the name of the array represents the address of the first element.

**ii.** I do not understand this as address of an address seems confusing.

**iii.** This should represent the value at address (that is `computer`) but the format specifier is `%p` and a random number gets printed in the output.

**iv.** This should mean value at address of address. This is again confusing.

I'm getting random values in the output. I understand that some of these could be because of undefined behavior. But if someone could clarify the meaning of these, I will be very grateful.

I also want to say that

```
printf ("%p\n",  **str1);
printf ("%p\n",  &&str1);
```

give compilation failed errors.

Comment: and the correct answer is `i` given by stdcall

Comment: @stdcall Thank you and what do the others mean?

Comment: "address of address" - there is no such thing. Ex: `ii` is wrong. `&str1` results in the address of the *pointer* `str1`. The address held *within* that pointer is that of the array of `char`, but the pointer itself has its own address.

Comment: You need `printf ("%s",    str1);`. `s` not `d` because you are printing string, not signed integer.

Comment: iii `*str1` is `'c'` maybe ascii value of `99`

Comment: @ST3 that's offtopic, OP don't want to print the string, he want to print the address of the string

Comment: @aste123 (iii) should be `%d` (or `%c`) as you are printing a character. Using `%p` there causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The only array in the sample code is the one produced by the string literal:

```
"computer"
```

In most contexts,<sup>1</sup> a string literal in C directs the compiler to produce (or act as if it had produced) an array somewhere in memory, with the contents of that array filled with the characters making up the string literal.  You are not allowed to write on the array elements—as if the array had type `const char [N]` for the appropriate integer constant *`N`*—but the array itself actually has type `char [N]`.  (The array may be, and on most modern compilers is-if-possible, placed in physically-read-only storage such as ROM or text space, although many compilers have directives that can affect this.  As others noted the rules are a bit different for C++.  The integer constant *`N`* is determined by the number of characters in the string literal, with a terminating `'\0'` `char` added.)

In general, given a variable `v` of type "array *N* of *T*" (for some type `T`), you simply write `&v` to get its address.  This is a value of type "pointer to array *N* of *T*".  This works for string literals as well:<sup>2</sup>

```
char (*p_a)[6] = &"hello";
```

Here `p_a` is a pointer to the array.  The difference between this and:

```
char *p_c = "world";
```

is that `p_c` is a pointer to a *single `char`* rather than a pointer to the (entire) array.  Hence `p_c[1]` is the *second* `char` in that array, the `'o'`.  But `p_a[1]` would be the entire 6-`char`-long array that follows the first array `"hello"`, if there were such an array (there is not one, and hence attempting to access `p_a[1]` produces undefined behavior).

Literally speaking, then, the answer to the question as asked is "none of them".  None of these expressions point to the entire array all at once!

Since we know that `"computer"` consists of 9 `char`s—the eight visible `char`s and the one terminating `'\0'`—we can take the value stored in `str1`, which is a pointer to the first of those 9 `char`s, and convert it (via casts and/or assignments) into the correct type, `char (*)[9]`, in order to get "the address of the (entire) array":

```
char (*answer_1)[9] = (void *)str1;
```

or:

```
((char (*)[9]) str1); /* answer2: produce the value, then ignore it */
```

for instance.

The thing about pointers and arrays in C, though, is that a pointer to the *first element* of an array is, for all practical purposes, "just as good" as a pointer to the *entire* array.  Hence just plain `str1`, which is a pointer to the first element of the 9-`char`-long array, is "just as good" as a pointer to the entire 9-`char`-long array.

This all sounds bizarre to people new to C.  Ages ago, I made up a graphic that displays the key difference; it can be found [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html).  The essence of the difference is the "size of the circle" rather than the "address value" itself.

Item number 2 (or I should say "ii") in your list, `&str1`, uses the fact that you have an actual object, `str1`, of type "pointer to `char`".  The address-of operator `&` gets you a pointer to that object: a value of type "pointer to (pointer to `char`)", or `char **`.  The value itself can be thought of as an arrow pointing to the variable `str1`, while the value stored in `str1` itself can be thought of as an arrow pointing to the `c` in `"computer"`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The main exception here is when the string literal is used as an initializer.  For instance:

```
char ch_array[9] = "computer";
```

exactly fills the 9-`char`-long array `ch_array`, without necessarily creating a second array anywhere.  In these cases you can control the actual `const`-ness of the resulting array; `ch_array` is not `const` and *is* something you can write to, so you can change the letters in this array, making it read "catputer", for instance, if you wish.

The C standards also allow you to make the array one element "too short", i.e., to fail to hold the terminating `'\0'`.  In this case the terminator is simply not stored anywhere.  There is no standard way to do this without creating such an object, although there was a proposal, which went nowhere, to use a final `\z` escape inside a string literal to get the same result.

Note that string concatenation:

```
char *x = "com" "put" "er";
```

does not insert the terminating `'\0'` between parts: the terminator is added *after* concatenation.  And, since writing on the anonymous array generated here produces undefined behavior, a compiler can (and good ones do) *share* string literals as well, possibly with "tail sharing",<sup>3</sup> so that:

```
char *s1 = "hello world", *s2 = "world";
```

might generate only one array, holding the `"hello world"` string, and make `s2` point to the `w` within that string.

<sup>2</sup>Back in the 1980s, a lot of compilers got this wrong.  To be fair, there was no standard for C at the time: the original ANSI C standard came out in December of 1989, so it was not until 1990 that there were any official rules one could apply to compiler-writers.

<sup>3</sup>"Tail sharing" is not a term of art, just a phrase I've made up here to attempt to describe the process.

Comment: You don't really need to make the exception for initializing from a string literal. The as-if rule means that you can still say that the literal exists.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: true, but this also gave me a place to hook into the special case that allows you to elide the terminator. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Lets take these in order:

1. `str` returns a pointer to the first character in the array
2. `&str` returns a pointer to the pointer (i.e. it points to where the variable `str` is located)
3. `*str` dereferences the pointer, and returns the value pointed to, in other words it returns the first character in the string (so it's no pointer at all)
4. `*&str` returns the same as 1, since the dereference and address-of operators cancel each other out
5. `&*str` is the same as above, the address-of and dereference cancel each other out

The difference between points 4 and 5 is the order in which the expression is evaluated, but the result is the same.

In your case with a `char` pointer, the "correct" way is 1.

---

As for your errors for `**str` and `&&str` it because `*str` results in a `char`, and that's not a type you can dereference. The one with double ampersand is because it's the logical and operator `&&` applied in an unary expression instead of a binary expression.

---

An unrelated point though: String literals are constant arrays of characters, with the size equal to the number of characters in the string plus one for the string terminator. That means that having a plain non-const pointer is wrong, the declaration should be either

```
const char *str = "computer";
```

or possible (don't know if it works in C)

```
char const *str = "computer";
```

Comment: In C (unlike C++), the type of a string literal is `char *`, not `const char *`, even though writing to them is forbidden.  This is for backward compatibility with K+R C.  Some compilers have an option to make the type be `const char *` (e.g. gcc's `-Wwrite-strings`) but turning it on for a large body of old code can trigger an enormous amout of fallout.

Comment: @Zack: string literals do not have pointer type in either language. They have type array of characters, const qualified in C++, shareable and logically constant in both.

Comment: @Deduplicator That level of detail will only confuse someone at the OP's level of understanding.

Comment: @Zack blurring the distinction between arrays and pointers is the best way to confuse anyone learning C.  As evidence, see how many posts there are on SO where people who thought they understood arrays, get tripped up by passing a 2-D array to a function

Comment: Technically, `&&str` fails not because the first `&` is applied to `&str`, but because `&&` is tokenized as a single `&&` operator, which is not allowed in this context (standard C has no unary `&&`).  (GNU C has an extension in which unary `&&` can be used to extract code-space addresses, but that's a gcc special.)

Answer (score 1):

All your examples cause undefined behavior, because `printf` with format specifier `%d` expects a `signed int`, not a pointer.

As [stdcall points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803541/which-one-is-the-correct-address-of-this-char-array-in-c#comment38499002_24803541), the proper format specifier for data pointers (though only for pointers to characters and `void`-pointers, the rest must, strictly speaking, be cast to either of them) is `%p`, which will print the pointer in an implementation-defined format.

This is an rvalue of type `char**`: `&str1` Cast to `void*` and print with `%p`
These are lvalues of type `char*`: `str1` `*&str1` Print the string with `%s` and the pointer value with `%p`
This is an rvalue of type `char*`: `&*str1` Same as above
This is an lvalue of type `char`: `*str1` Print with `%c`

All `char*` point to the same object.

Be aware that even though string literals have type `char[]` for historic reasons, they are constants which might be shared: Trying to change them results in UB.

Answer (score 0):

printf ("\n%d", *str1);   // iii

Don't print a random number, but the ascii value of first char

*str1 is, infact, value of first char 'c' == 99

with *(str1 + i) you access element i of str1

Answer (score 0):

```
printf ("%d", str1);   // i
```

This is the address of your "string", where you `char` array is stored (equivalent to `&str[0]`). The type of `str1` is obvisouly `char*` which does not match the `%d` specifier, but most of implementation will output the address as an integer.

```
printf ("\n%d", &str1);   // ii
```

`str1` points to the address of the first `char` in `str1` (i.e. `&str[0]`), so `&str1` points to `str1`:

```
&str1 -> str1 -> "computer"

printf ("\n%d", *str1);   // iii
```

This is simply equivalent to `str1[0]` which is `'c'`. Since you specify `%d` specifier, the value output is the `ansi` value of `'c'`.

```
printf ("\n%d", *&str1);  // iv
printf ("\n%d", &*str1);  // v
```

Well, `*&a` and `&*a` are equivalent in most (all?) cases to `a`, so here you just get the first behaviour.

```
printf ("\n%d", **str1);
```

`str1` is a pointer, so you can dereference it to get `'c'`, but `*str1` is `'c'` and you can't dereference a `char`.

```
printf ("\n%d", &&str1);
```

`&str1` is the address of `str1` but it's not a variable so it does not have any address so `&&str1` is not possible (the address of the address of `str1` does not exist).

As mentionned in the other answers, the correct way to output a pointer is `%p`. You get random value for all cases (except `iii` normally) because `str1` does not always have the same address.